# How to deploy Tibco GI to windows 10

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tibco, tibco-gi

I've a requirement to work on Tibco General interface application. But creating a sample Tibco GI in today's time is difficult as it supports Windows 7 or less. Can anyone suggest any work around that they have used to make tibco GI sample application in Windows 10 or above?
thanks

We have tried to find a server with old windows configuration, but its not available.